# How to offset UIView's "hitbox" (Mapbox MGLAnnotationView bug)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mapbox, touch-event

What I want to do is to offset the UIView's hitbox by a half of its height up, so it will still draw its contents as usual, but register touches in an offset "hitbox". I tried to offset UIView's bounds but it also changes the way its contents are drawn.

---

[Detailed original issue description on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7450)